# Webserver Partitioning Scheme

Tags: linux, partition

How would you allocate around 18.5 GB (don't laugh) on a linux install for a webserver? I'm installing opensuse 11.3.  I know I need to allocate a lot to `/var`, but not sure how much to allocate to `/`.  Here's what I currently have:

```
Swap   1GB
/boot  47.07MB
/      2.14 GB
/var   10 GB
```

Should I split between `/` partition and `/var`? 5 and 5GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create only `/`, `swap` and may be `/boot` partitions. If it is not clear why to partition and how much, it is much better to create a big `/`.

Comment: ---sounds good!

Answer (score 3):

Partition 0.5 GiB of disk space for a `/boot` partition, and leave the rest for use with LVM (Logical Volume Management).

Then allocate, say, 10.0 GiB of Logical Volumes (LVs) for swap and filesystems. Here is a sample breakdown that should work to start:

- 1.0 GiB: swap
- 3.0 GiB: `/`
- 1.0 GiB: `/home`
- 5.0 GiB: `/var`

This will leave you with roughly 8.0 GiB of unallocated space in LVM to use to expand any partition that starts to look cramped. The great thing about this approach is that it allows you to defer space allocation decisions to the future, when you will actually know more about your disk usage needs.